# Trying to extract string from another string in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a for loop that loops through a list of .pdf files contained in a text file `filelist.txt`.  From these file names I extract a series of tokens which are used to eventually rename some output files.  This loop works fine.  But I also need to substring some of those token variables into other variables so that I can build a "copy to" directory string.  I've tried the following but it doesn't work, I suspect because the "in" source in the subsequent "for" loops is a token variable not a file.  Here is the code I currently have.

```
    @echo off
```

`SET myPath=..\watch\
echo %myPath%
cd ..\watch\

REM create a file containing all of the case pdfs to process
dir /b /a-d *.pdf > filelist.txt

REM for each filename in the file list
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=_." %%F in (filelist.txt) do (
   echo Splitting and Encrypting %%F_%%G_%%H_%%I.%%J
   echo Cohort %%F
   echo Unit %%G
   echo Case %%H
   echo Case Name %%I
   echo Extension %%J

REM Now determine the new location to copy entire output
REM Extract Unit number
REM    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=U" %%K in (%%G) do
REM       echo Original %%G
REM       echo Prefix %%K
REM       echo Unit Number %%L
REM    )

REM Extract Case number
REM   for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=C" %%O in ("%%G") do
REM      echo Prefix %%O
REM      echo Unit Number %%P
REM   )
)


cd ..\test`

<\pre>

It's been years since I've done any batch programming so I'm very rusty.  How can I make this work.  The input file is of the form `MS2014_U01_C2_John-Doe.pdf`.  I want to extract the 01 from the variable `%%G` and the 2 from the variable `%%H`.

Thanks for your help in advance  - John

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unnedded characters as delimiters in aditional inner for loops to retrieve the needed data

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=_." %%F in (filelist.txt
) do for /f "delims=U" %%g in ("%%G"
) do for /f "delims=H" %%h in ("%%H"
) do (
   echo Splitting and Encrypting %%F_%%G_%%H_%%I.%%J
   echo Cohort %%F
   echo Unit %%G
   echo ... Unit Number %%g
   echo Case %%H
   echo ... Case Number %%h
   echo Case Name %%I
   echo Extension %%J
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
REM Now determine the new location to copy entire output
REM Extract Unit number
rem
rem this must be executed in the context of the FOR...%%F...DO else %%G is out-of-context
rem note that %%G should be "quoted" else will try to read file with name %%G!
rem %%K will be set to the first group of characters following any initial "U"
rem and up to end or next "U" or sequence of "U"
rem %%L will be set to the second such group (if it exists)
rem note that " (" must follow "DO" to execute a block
rem
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=U" %%K in ("%%G") do (
       echo Original %%G
       echo Prefix %%K
       echo Unit Number %%L

REM Extract Case number
rem
rem this must be executed in the context of the FOR...%%F...DO else %%H is out-of-context
rem and also in the context of the FOR...%%K...DO else %%K,%%L are is out-of-context
rem note that %%H, not %%G contains the case
rem %%O will be set to the first group of characters following any initial "C"
rem and up to end or next "C" or sequence of "C"
rem %%P will be set to the second such group (if it exists)
rem note that " (" must follow "DO" to execute a block
rem
   for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=C" %%O in ("%%G") do (
    echo Splitting and Encrypting %%F_%%G_%%H_%%I.%%J
    echo Cohort %%F
    echo Unit %%G
    echo Case %%H
    echo Case Name %%I
    echo Extension %%J
    echo Prefix %%K
    echo Unit Number %%L
    echo Prefix %%O
    echo Unit Number %%P
rem this closes the FOR...%%O...DO (
    )
rem this closes the FOR...%%K...DO (
   )
rem this closes the FOR...%%F...DO (
)
```

change comments inline with `rem` keywords lower-case. Untested.